# TimeOfDay issue in EF Core 6 and SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have a problem querying a SQLite database using EF Core 6.

The query is pretty simple:

```
_context.SomeTable
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(x => x.SomeDateTimeColumn.Value.TimeOfDay <= DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay)
        .ToList();
```

The exception message states that the query could not be translated:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet().Where(t => t.SomeDateTimeColumn.Value.TimeOfDay <= DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation...

My problem is that, according to the documentation, `DateTime.TimeOfDay` should be supported by the SQLite database provider. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/functions#date-and-time-functions

Does anyone know the reason for this or could point me to what I'm missing?

Comment: Only if the column in database is a DateTime.  Try following : .Where(x => DateTime.Parse(x.SomeDateTimeColumn.Value).TimeOfDay <= DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay)

Comment: @jdweng you mean I should change the columns type to varchar? cause otherwise this doesn't compile

Comment: No.  It means the c# class is set to DateTime.  Not the database.  You need to check the database table to see if column is DateTime.  You are also using _context which means there is an edmx mapping file.  I think error indicates there is a mismatch in the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TimeSpan` values are not yet supported by EF Core. Please upvote issue [#18844](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18844).

Hmm, you might be able to do it using `Ticks`. But the precision might be kinda bad.

```
x.SomeDateTimeColumn.Value.Ticks % 864000000000 <= DateTime.Now.Ticks % 864000000000
```

For better precision, you can [manually map](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping) the `julianday` function.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Also thanks for linking the issue, Microsofts SQLite EF Core provider documentation confused me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be related to the way DateTime works.

Instead of using:

```
_context.SomeTable
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => x.SomeDateTimeColumn.Value.TimeOfDay <= DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay)
    .ToList();
```

Try this:

```
_context.SomeTable
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => x.SomeDateTimeColumn <= DateTime.Now)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This does solve the error, but the query isn't correct anymore. The query should only evaluate the time of the column without looking at the day.

Comment: @Ammel, What about this? _context.SomeTable
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => x.SomeDateTimeColumn.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString() <= DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString())
    .ToList();

Comment: I changed <= to == in your snippet (cause comparing strings like that in c# doesn't work) and it didn't throw an exception, which makes it seem like TimeOfDay isn't the problem after all?

Comment: Would you share the exception details, please?